# How to encrypt a audio file which will be downloaded from web, this file should have limit to be able to get played only on 3 PC's

Tags: java, encryption, drm, rights-management

I am searching for a way in Java or Asp that can allow me to encrypt a file and upload it to the website. When somebody downloads it and plays on the players available on the computer it should track that computer and should get played only if the no. of PC's on which this file is played is less than 3.

Is there a way to do it. I thought of flv by scripting something in flash but not that much convinced as it will have eaasy way out..

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for a DRM solution, such as Protected WMA files. Note that any DRM solution is going to require a DRM rights management server and compatible player to properly license the file on download.

Also note that such systems for protection of media are largely on the way out due to customer frustration, with so many online music stores going under and their customers no longer being able to "activate" their purchases.